# friendly_id, Seeding database, Undefined method 'friendly_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id

In a Rails 3 app, I am trying to write seeds (in db/seeds.rb) for a model that uses [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id):

```
# /db/seeds.rb
Page.create(:title => "Default page", :content => "Default content of the default page")
```

When I run `rake db:seed` the task fails.  Below is the gist when running with `--trace`:

```
rake aborted!
undefined local variable or method `friendly_id' for #<Class:0x007fa1de992ac8>
/Users/cornelius/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@usg/gems/activerecord-3.2.5/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
/Users/cornelius/Sites/usg/app/models/page.rb:2:in `<class:Page>'
/Users/cornelius/Sites/usg/app/models/page.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

Here is the model:

```
# /app/models/page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend friendly_id
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end
```

I am using `friendly_id` as a Gem:

```
# /Gemfile
gem 'friendly_id'
```

Any help?

Comment: Did you try using "extend FriendlyId"?

Comment: The docs (https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) suggest that it should be `extend FriendlyId` rather than `extend friendly_id` - but I'm not going to write an answer like that and steal Dave's rep.

Comment: @Shadwell Don't worry; ipd will ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model you need to extend the class properly, the classname is FriendlyId, rather than friendly_id.

As a convention in Ruby and Rails, classnames are CamelCase and filenames are snake_case.

Your Page model should read:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end
```